# How to make lazy panel in ICEface 4.3?

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, icefaces, icefaces-3

I have data ICEfaces 4.3 Datatable in which every row has one panel and its collapsed by default. Even it is collapsed its content view is getting rendered which making page slow.
Here is sample code,

```
    <ace:dataTable  var="myVar" value="#{mybeanobj}"
            paginator="true"
            paginatorPosition="top"
            pageCount="5"
            rowIndexVar="row"
            rows="20" >
            <ace:column>
            <ace:panel id="details" toggleable="true"  styleClass="details-marker" collapsed="true">
                <f:facet name="header">
                        <h:outputText value="my header"/>
                </f:facet>
                <h:outputText value="myVar.v1"/>
                <h:outputText value="myVar.v2"/>
                <h:outputText value="myVar.v3"/>
                <h:outputText value="myVar.v4"/>
                <h:outputText value="myVar.v5"/>
                <h:outputText value="myVar.v6"/>
                <h:outputText value="myVar.v7"/>
                </ace:panel>
            </ace:column>
        </ace:dataTable>
```

How I can make panel lazy so that content will be loaded only when its toggled rather than during page render ?

Comment: Please edit your question to be more specific and try to provide a [mcve]. There are plenty of different kinds of panels from each component framework you added a tag for.

Comment: You can atach Ajax listener to the 'toggle' or 'close' event to perform content loading (see http://res.icesoft.org/docs/v4_latest/ace/tld/ace/panel.html).